# HttpClient aumentando IIS CurrentConnections

Tags: c#, .net, assincronismo

Enfrento uma situação em uma webapi em que um endpoint faz em alguns casos uma requisição via HttpClient através de um método síncrono, porém sempre que essa requisição é efetuada o total do indicador CurrentConnections do IIS é incrementado e nunca reduz.

Classe responsável pela requisição Http:

```
    public class HttpDatasource
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient() { Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60) };

        public static class HttpDataSource
        {
            internal static async Task<T> HttpGetId<T>(string endPoint, string id)
            {
                var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{endPoint}/{id}");

                var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                return ParseHttpResponse<T>(response.StatusCode, body);
            }
        }
    }
```

Trecho que faz a chamada http no método **síncrono**:

```
var taskGetFromHttp = Task.Run(
() => HttpDataSource.HttpGetId<ConsolidatedPositionCondensed>($"{baseURL}/api/GetBalance", accountId));
taskGetFromHttp.Wait();
var balance = taskGetFromHttp.Result;
```

**CurrentConnections** Incrementando sem fim:

[image: CurrentConnections]

O que poderia causar esse comportamento?

Cogitei utilizar .Dispose() na Task, porém não ficou claro se esse seria o meio correto de resolver a situação.

Estou utilizando .Net Framework 4.7.2

Comment: `static`??? a sua classe tem problemas e não pode esse recurso ser feito com essa classe, por motivos já citados por você mesmo!

Comment: @novic obrigado pela sua resposta, mas não compreendi o que quis dizer.

Comment: Quando se trabalha com classe `static` a mesma só é encerrada ao termino de programa, fora o problema de aumento de concorrência por aquelas que estão em aberto também causa diversos problemas. Você precisa força o termino dessas pequisas inclusive dessa classe e trabalhar com a instância é melhor do que aquilo que fica o tempo todo na memória sem necessidade, utilizando recursos do sistema!

Comment: @novic Entendo a questão de ficar o tempo todo na memória, mas essa chamada ocorre inúmeras vezes durante o dia e após leitura de alguns artigos relacionados a problemas com a HttpClient achei prudente manter a mesma instância para todas chamadas. https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

Comment: O Link do comentário é para aspnet core que tem um implementação melhor do que a antiga, se você vai chamar varias vezes, isso não impede de criar uma instância única para cada chamada e nela tratar e fechar o socket de cada uma e consequentemente avisar que esse recurso não é mais necessário, isso seria o ideal, quando você mantem um variável que abre e fecha requisição o controle fica perdido no meio do caminho e causa consumo excessivo de memória e baixo desempenho ...! isso não é utilizar de maneira inteligente o recurso, o link é outra plataforma do net, não cabe aqui ... a ideia sim!

Comment: Tente criar um classe onde a abertura acontece de alguma forma e ao termino da requisição (podendo até ser um erro) você consiga fechar isso e dar um `Dispose` avisando a aplicação de liberação do recurso quando puder ... !!! Isso é o ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### `using`

O método `HttpClient.GetAsync` retorna um `HttpResponseMessage`, que por sua vez implementa `IDisposable`.

Então no mínimo você deveria estar fazendo:

```
        internal static async Task<T> HttpGetId<T>(string endPoint, string id)
        {
            using ( var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync($"{endPoint}/{id}") )
            {
                // Resto do código aqui.
            }
        }
```

Isso *pode* ajudar a resolver seu problema, mas não tive como testar. O que *realmente* resolveria o seu problema seria configurar o `HttpClient` para fechar a conexão assim que terminar. Ver esse [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36357943/c-sharp-how-to-set-httpclient-keep-alive-to-false).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta André, talvez eu tenha esquecido de mencionar que o serviço que está com a métrica de CurrentConnections alta é o serviço que está enviando a requisição Http. Será que para essa situação é válido o Keep alive = false?

Comment: Sim. Observe, o keep alive em true *mantém* as conexões abertas. Pelo que entendi você quer baixar o número de CurrentConnections, Para tanto pode-se fechar automaticamente as conexões. Que o que o keep alive false faz.